# How to change color of an image from a prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button made as a prefab. I would like to instantiate it as a GameObject. Buttons have a component attached by default. I want to access it and assign a color while instantiating. I tried a few ways but got errors. So what is a way to change the image color of an instantiated prefab?

As a 2d UI element, it renders in a canvas.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject button;

GameObject child = Instantiate(button, new Vector2(0,0), Quaternion.identity);
//error: not a monobehavior object.
//Image rend = child.GetComponent<Image>();
//rend.tintColor = Color.blue;

//no renderer.
 // Renderer boxRenderer = child.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
 // boxRenderer.material.color = Color.blue;

 //child.setparent();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely accidentally used the wrong `Image` class in your script, such as the one defined in `UnityEngine.UIElements.Image`, `System.Drawing.Image`, or maybe a class named `Image` in your own project.

You're using UGUI components (from the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace), so you want to be using `UnityEngine.UI.Image`. Double-check which `Image` class you're using and make the necessary changes to ensure you're using the correct one. Then you can change its `color` property.

Comment: Yes, that is it. I was skeptical about the import between `UIElements` and `UI`. Thank you for clarifying.